# PHP Script is not inserting values into Database

Tags: php, mysql

For whatever reason, whenever I submit the form, it doesn't add the inputted data to the database. It was working before... Which I think is what's frustrating me the most. I came back to it a couple of hours later, and surprise! Not inserting new rows into the database. Perhaps there's a slight error I may have done subconsciously by accident? Nothing stands out to me, though. :(

refer.html: http://pastebin.com/d1xQUJLR

generator.php: http://pastebin.com/CE2UX8zs

main.js: http://pastebin.com/CSQh9DKs

Comment: Add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened. Now go out there and debug it Tiger!

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed some bugs in your code ;)

```
<?php
include_once "access.php";
$ref_email = $_POST["tf_ref_email"];
$ref_username = $_POST["tf_ref_username"];
$ref_ign = $_POST["tf_ref_ign"];

$access = new Access();
$crux = $access->getCrux();
$anchor = $access->getAnchor();
$user = $access->getUser();

try {
    $pdo = new PDO($anchor, $user, $crux);
    $stq = "INSERT INTO referred_users
 (ref_id, ref_email, ref_username, ref_ign, ref_awarded, new_email, new_awarded)
 VALUES (:ref_id, :ref_email, :ref_username, :ref_ign, :ref_awarded, :new_email, :new_awarded)";

    for($i = 0; $i < min(count($_POST["emails"]), 10); $i++) {
        $ref_id = $_POST["ref_ids"][$i];
        $new_email = $_POST["emails"][$i];

        $new_ref_id = checkId($ref_id, $pdo);

        $query = $pdo->prepare($stq);
        $results = $query->execute(
            array(
                ':ref_id'       => $new_ref_id,
                ':ref_email'    => $ref_email,
                ':ref_username' => $ref_username,
                ':ref_ign'      => $ref_ign,
                ':ref_awarded'  => '0',
                ':new_email'    => $new_email,
                ':new_awarded'  => '0'
            )
        );

        $to = $new_email;
        $subject = "Check out this AMAZING Minecraft RP Server!";
        $message = "You have been invited to join " . $ref_ign . " in Arithia! Enter your Referral ID in the provided link to get a head start on your first character!" . "\n";
        $message .= "Referral ID: " . $new_ref_id . "\n";
        $message .= "Redeem Rewards: " . "http://www.graphicgoldfish.com/referral/referral.html" . "\n";
        $message .= "By redeeming your referral, you will get:" . "\n";
        $message .= "- 300 Credit Points" . "\n";
        $message .= "- 50 Ducats" . "\n";
        $message .= "- 25 Cooked Beef" . "\n";
        $message .= "- Identification Tome" . "\n";
        $message .= "We look forward to seeing you in Arithia! For more information, visit: http://www.arithia.com" . "\n";
        $headers = "From: $ref_email";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

function checkId($id, $con) {
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT ref_id FROM referred_users WHERE ref_id = :ref_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':ref_id', $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $new_id = (string)rand(1000000, 9999999);

        return checkId($new_id, $con);
    }

    return $id;
}
```